# Error using rlog(), DSEeq2 _ Error in x %*% Rinv : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Tags: r

I attempt to calculate differential expression using DESeq2. I used my BAM files (from TOPHAT) and gff3 annotation table to create a SummarizedExperiment (se_2).

I also tried using the example "airway" data set and obtain similar error: "Error in x %*% Rinv : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments". If use rlog() or DESeq() I obtain this error. It seems you have this error if you use a dataframe instead of a matrix ([see the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906804/how-to-solve-the-error-requires-numeric-complex-matrix-vector-arguments-in-r)). In my case I did not change the object class.

I rebuilt the "DESeq2" package and it did not solve the problem.

```
>sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

>se_2
 class: SummarizedExperiment 
 dim: 59225 12 
 exptData(0):
 assays(1): counts
 rownames(59225): Bo00285s010 Bo00285s020 ... Bo9g186200 Bo9g186210
 rowData metadata column names(0):
 colnames(12): 511_T2_Late_Wood 513_T2_Early_Wood ... 569_T8_Late_Camb 571_T8_Early_Camb
    colData names(5): stade plant SampleName Bam.file file

> dds <- DESeqDataSet(se_2, design = ~ stade)
> rld <- rlog(dds)
Error in x %*% Rinv : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

Thanks for your help. Please let me know if I did not give enough information.
Nico

Comment: I terminated R. Loaded the environment and it ran. I do no believe in spirit... but sometime you wonder.

Comment: Spirit exists. http://www.chemcolor.si/images/topila-razredcila-kemikalije/denaturirani-spirit_v.jpg