# Matrix Error: Requires numeric in R

Tags: r, matrix

```
Phi <- as.matrix(cbind(1, train.data)) # add a column of 1 as phi_0
train.len <- 75
eta <- 0.01 # Learning rate
epsilon <- 0.001 # 
tau.max <- 75 # Maximum number of iterations

T <- ifelse(train.label == c0, eval(parse(text=c0)),eval(parse(text=c1))) labels

W <- matrix(,nrow=tau.max, ncol=ncol(Phi)) # Empty Weight vector
W[1,] <- runif(ncol(Phi)) # Random initial values for weight vector

error.trace <- matrix(0,nrow=tau.max, ncol=1) # Placeholder for errors
error.trace[1] <- sum((Phi%*%W[1,])*T<0)/train.len*100
```

`train.data` looks like:

```
x1    x2    x3    x4    y
5.1   3.5   1.4   0.2   C1
4.7   3.2   1.3   0.2   C1
35.0  3.6   1.4   0.2   C1
```

The problem happens in the last line. I checked some other posts ([Matrix expression causes error "requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906804/how-to-solve-the-error-requires-numeric-complex-matrix-vector-arguments-in-r)) . they say to ensure that the data is in matrix format and I also checked they are both numeric (`Phi` and `W`).

The error I get is

> Error in Phi %*% W[1, ] : 
>     requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Comment: What would you expect to happen to the `y` column in `train.data` during matrix multiplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get no error when I generate some toy data: `train.data <- rnorm(75)`. What is your `train.data`? A data frame? If so, what is `sapply(train.data, class)`? I suspect you have factors / characters. In that case, your matrix `Phi` will be a character matrix, instead of a numerical one.

Maybe you should try using:

```
Phi <- cbind(1, data.matrix(train.data))
```

Read `?data.matrix` for more. Another way is to use:

```
Phi <- cbind(1, sapply(train.data, as.numeric))
```

---

**Update**

Indeed you have a column `y`, which is either a factor or character column. My solution above will work. But, I don't know your context, so you should ask yourself whether it makes sense to include `y` column for computation. If you don't want it, drop it and use:

```
Phi <- cbind(1, as.matrix(train.data[,1:4]))
```

Comment: Doh! This is what happens when you do R at 3am! I totally overlooked my Y column. Yep, dropped and it's all good now. Thanks!