# Matrix multiplication from the data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm studying matrix multiplication in R. I want to do matrix multiplication from the data frame.
Let's say I have `df` and `beta` as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(one = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                 x1=c(21,34,24,35,42),
                 x2=c(32,24,13,21,35))
beta<-c(1,2,2)
```

`df` is a 5 by 3 matrix and `beta` is 3 by 1 matrix. I want to multiply `beta` to `df` to get a 5 by 1 column matrix. Usually, using the standard multiplication, the code should be

```
df%*%beta
```

I want to do this multiplication and also give it a column name `df_beta`.
But since there are variable names on each column, this matrix multiplication doesn't work. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"%*%"` has no "data.frame" method. This is reasonable because there is no guarantee that all columns in a data frame are numeric.

To get a result, you need `as.matrix(df) %*% beta`. But you take full responsibility to ensure the type conversion gives correct result (watch out for potential character matrix, for which I had a discussion here: [Matrix multiplication in R: requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40325465/4891738)).

Once it executes correctly, to store the result in a new column, use

```
df$df_beta <- c(as.matrix(df) %*% beta)
```