# Neuralnet package in R keeps giving error message on numeric/vector/matrix arguments

Tags: r, neural-network

I have a data frame named [IED2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LyZHpcTIEMFyxbylZTVmn6yu4emS0CPL). I tried to use `neuralnet` package in R to develop a forecasting model on one column `Prop.of.Proper.Cleared` of this `IED2`. Since the data is in terms of time-series, I used `createTimeSlices` method and expanding -window rolling forecasting to create the training and testing datasets. But then when running the `for` loop below, I kept getting the error message
that I could not fi, despite checking to make sure the data type of each columns is `integer`.

> ```
> Error in cbind(1, pred) %*% weights[[num_hidden_layers + 1]] :   
> requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
> ```

**My Code**

```
 timeSlices <- createTimeSlices(1:nrow(IED2), 
                                initialWindow = 90, horizon = 62, fixedWindow = FALSE)

trainSlices <- timeSlices[[1]]
testSlices <- timeSlices[[2]]

test = NULL
net.sqrt = NULL
err = NULL
col_list <- paste(c(colnames(IED2[,5:7])),collapse="+")
col_list <- paste(c("Prop.of.Proper.Clear~",col_list),collapse="")
f <- formula(col_list)

for(i in 1:2000){
  set.seed(1)
  net.sqrt[i] <- neuralnet(f, data = IED2[trainSlices[[i]],] , algorithm = "rprop+", hidden=2, threshold=0.01, 
                        learningrate = 0.0001, linear.output = TRUE, err.fct="sse")
  test[i] <- compute(net.sqrt[i], IED2[testSlices[[i]],5:7])
  err[i] <- ((test[i]$net.result - IED2[testSlices[[i]],13])^2)/nrow(IED2[testSlices[[i]],])
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Sample Dataset with `dput`

```
structure(list(DoW = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 1L), Mnth = c(1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L,
 0L, 0L, 0L), Prop.of.Proper.Clear = c(0.333333333, 
 0.2, 0.333333333, 0.125, 0, 0)), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,  7L, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Take a look at this for some pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906804/matrix-expression-causes-error-requires-numeric-complex-matrix-vector-arguments

Comment: I took a look at the link you showed, but it's not relevant to `neuralnet` package. Still left puzzled.